# Filtering with checkboxes using jQuery - preserve the selections in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786090/jquery-multiple-checkbox-filtering) and with success implemented this as a 2-dimensional product viewer with filtering.

As I really appreciate the people developing and sharing this code.

I would like it to be possible for the selections to be preserved when clicking back from a product? Maybe it's possible to get the selections showed as variables in the URL when a checkbox is checked, so in that way you can click back to the same selection?

Another thing, I have tried to add a series of radio buttons, that has nothing to do with the actual checkboxes or jQuery, but for some reason the jQuery reacts to the radio buttons when clicked. Are there any way to "disable" this? Even if the radio buttons are untouched, when filtering with the existing checkboxes, it behaves wrongly by hiding everything when supposed to show everything.

```
    <div class="flowers-wrap">
    <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Filter flowers by colour:</strong>
    </p>
    <form>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="1" />Kartofler</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="2" />Gulerødder</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="3" />Løg</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="4" />Agurker</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="5" />Peber</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="6" />Rødbeder</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="7" />Selleri</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="8" />Andre</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="9" />Salat</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="12" />Emballage</label>
        <br>
    </form>
    <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Filter flowers by size:</strong>
    </p>
    <form>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t10" />Frasortering - sten/grus</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t11" />Vaske</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t12" />Polere</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t13" />Tørre</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t14" />Sortering</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t15" />Skrælle</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t16" />Skære</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t17" />Transport</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t18" />Veje/tælle</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t19" />Pakke/fylde</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t21" />Storkøkken</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t22" />Palletering</label>
        <br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="flowers">
    <div class="flower" data-id="3-Dimensionel skiveskærermaskine" data-category="8 5 3 2 1 t16 ">3-Dimensionel skiveskærermaskine</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="3D-skærer til Sticks og tern" data-category="9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 t16 ">3D-skærer til Sticks og tern</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk gulerodsskærer og slicer" data-category="2 t16 ">Automatisk gulerodsskærer og slicer</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk gulerodsskærer og slicer" data-category="2 t16 ">Automatisk gulerodsskærer og slicer</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk kassefylder" data-category="9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 t17 t19 ">Automatisk kassefylder</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk løgskræller USM-100A" data-category="3 t15 ">Automatisk løgskræller USM-100A</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk Pallelaster" data-category="12 t22 ">Automatisk Pallelaster</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk strapmaskine incl. påsætning af hjørnebeskytter" data-category="12 t22 ">Automatisk strapmaskine incl. påsætning af hjørnebeskytter</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk Vejemaskine" data-category="3 1 t18 ">Automatisk Vejemaskine</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Basisenhed for manuel udskæring" data-category="9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 t16 ">Basisenhed</div>
            </div>
```

Javascript:

```
       var byProperty = [],
       byColor = [];

   $("input[name=fl-colour]").on("change", function () {
       if (this.checked) byProperty.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
       else removeA(byProperty, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
   });

   $("input[name=fl-size]").on("change", function () {
       if (this.checked) byColor.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
       else removeA(byColor, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
   });


   $("input").on("change", function () {
       var str = "Include items \n";
       var selector = '',
           cselector = '',
           nselector = '';

       var $lis = $('.flowers > div'),
           $checked = $('input:checked');

       if ($checked.length) {

           if (byProperty.length) {
               if (str == "Include items \n") {
                   str += "    " + "with (" + byProperty.join(',') + ")\n";
                   $($('input[name=fl-colour]:checked')).each(function (index, byProperty) {
                       if (selector === '') {
                           selector += "[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";
                       } else {
                           selector += ",[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";
                       }
                   });
               } else {
                   str += "    AND " + "with (" + byProperty.join(' OR ') + ")\n";
                   $($('input[name=fl-size]:checked')).each(function (index, byProperty) {
                       selector += "[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";
                   });
               }
           }

           if (byColor.length) {
               if (str == "Include items \n") {
                   str += "    " + "with (" + byColor.join(' OR ') + ")\n";
                   $($('input[name=fl-size]:checked')).each(function (index, byColor) {
                       if (selector === '') {
                           selector += "[data-category~='" + byColor.id + "']";
                       } else {
                           selector += ",[data-category~='" + byColor.id + "']";
                       }
                   });
               } else {
                   str += "    AND " + "with (" + byColor.join(' OR ') + ")\n";
                   $($('input[name=fl-size]:checked')).each(function (index, byColor) {
                       if (cselector === '') {
                           cselector += "[data-category~='" + byColor.id + "']";
                       } else {
                           cselector += ",[data-category~='" + byColor.id + "']";
                       }
                   });
               }
           }



           $lis.hide();
           console.log(selector);
           console.log(cselector);
           console.log(nselector);

           if (cselector === '' && nselector === '') {
               $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).show();
           } else if (cselector === '') {
               $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).filter(nselector).show();
           } else if (nselector === '') {
               $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).show();
           } else {
               $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).filter(nselector).show();
           }

       } else {
           $lis.show();
       }

       $("#result").html(str);

    });
    function removeA(arr) {
       var what, a = arguments,
           L = a.length,
           ax;
       while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
           what = a[--L];
           while ((ax = arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
               arr.splice(ax, 1);
           }
       }
       return arr;
    }
```

I fiddled the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/azR83/4/).

I thank you all in advance :-)

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. Also, please don't circumvent the rules regarding JSFiddle links by adding a blockquote to the post.

Comment: your problem is more CSS related than any of the question tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten help for the fist part now, and I have now successfully been able to get the products listed 2 side by side.

Here's the [Jfiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/azR83/4/)

```
body {
    font-family:'Arial';
    color:#646464;
}
.continents-wrap {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    margin:0 5% 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
.flowers-wrap {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    margin:0 5% 0 0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;    
}
.flowers {
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    border:1px solid #FF00FF;
}
.flowers div {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:68px;
    line-height:68px;
    padding:0 10px;
    background:#eee;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #00FF00;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It would be so great if I could the the code to paste variables to the URL, as this could help preserve the selections when coming back from looking at a product in detail. Is there anyone who can help here?

Another thing, I have tried to add a series of radio buttons, that has nothing to do with the actual checkboxes or jQuery, but for some reason the jQuery reacts to the radio buttons when clicked. Are there any way to "disable" this?

[JSFiddle for that is here](http://jsfiddle.net/mazeymazey/azR83/6/)

```
<label style="font-size:12px;">    <input type="radio" onclick="window.location='?page=product-list&katsel=1'"> Vis alle</label><br/>
<label style="font-size:12px;">    <input type="radio" onclick="window.location='?page=product-list&katsel=2'"> Vis noget</label><br/>


<div class="flowers-wrap">
    <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Filter flowers by colour:</strong>
    </p>
    <form>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="1" />Kartofler</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="2" />Gulerødder</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="3" />Løg</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="4" />Agurker</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="5" />Peber</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="6" />Rødbeder</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="7" />Selleri</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="8" />Andre</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="9" />Salat</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" id="12" />Emballage</label>
        <br>
    </form>
    <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Filter flowers by size:</strong>
    </p>
    <form>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t10" />Frasortering - sten/grus</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t11" />Vaske</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t12" />Polere</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t13" />Tørre</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t14" />Sortering</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t15" />Skrælle</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t16" />Skære</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t17" />Transport</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t18" />Veje/tælle</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t19" />Pakke/fylde</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t21" />Storkøkken</label>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size:12px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" id="t22" />Palletering</label>
        <br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="flowers">
    <div class="flower" data-id="3-Dimensionel skiveskærermaskine" data-category="8 5 3 2 1 t16 ">3-Dimensionel skiveskærermaskine</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="3D-skærer til Sticks og tern" data-category="9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 t16 ">3D-skærer til Sticks og tern</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk gulerodsskærer og slicer" data-category="2 t16 ">Automatisk gulerodsskærer og slicer</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk gulerodsskærer og slicer" data-category="2 t16 ">Automatisk gulerodsskærer og slicer</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk kassefylder" data-category="9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 t17 t19 ">Automatisk kassefylder</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk løgskræller USM-100A" data-category="3 t15 ">Automatisk løgskræller USM-100A</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk Pallelaster" data-category="12 t22 ">Automatisk Pallelaster</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk strapmaskine incl. påsætning af hjørnebeskytter" data-category="12 t22 ">Automatisk strapmaskine incl. påsætning af hjørnebeskytter</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Automatisk Vejemaskine" data-category="3 1 t18 ">Automatisk Vejemaskine</div>
    <div class="flower" data-id="Basisenhed for manuel udskæring" data-category="9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 t16 ">Basisenhed</div>
            </div>
```

Even if the radio buttons are untouched, when filtering with the existing checkboxes, it behaves wrongly by hiding everything when supposed to show everything.

---- UPDATE ----

I no longer need the second part where the URL are taken in consideration. Therefore I close the question.