# Using jQuery to toggle visibility of various divs based on two sets of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a large number of divs/articles that contain contact info for a bunch of wilderness guides.  I'm trying to toggle the visibility of each div based on two sets of checkboxes - One set for the activity the guide specializes in (fishing, hunting, etc) and one set for the state they're in (Alaska, Colorado, etc).

There's a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786090/jquery-multiple-checkbox-filtering) that I've been trying to follow, but I'm missing something(s).

Update:  The filters mostly work currently, but independently of each other, not together.  If someone chooses FISHING from the first group of filters and ALASKA from the second group of filters, it currently shows all guides that offer fishing, regardless if they're in Alaska or not because fishing is checked.  The other issue is if 2 states are checked, it won't show any results because no div will have 2 states for classes...  an AND vs OR problem.

The end goal is for user to select as many sports and states as they'd like and filter out (hide) the divs that don't match both the sport(s) and state(s) chosen.  Ideally, as a no JS fallback, I'd like to start by showing all divs and then removing visibility as filter criteria isn't met, but I'll tackle that next.

**Here's the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4SDesignStudio/o1myyjxd/7/)**

**The quick and dirty HTML:**

```
    <div class="sport-wrapper">
        <h2>Choose a Sport:</h2>        
        <ul>
            <li><label for="fish"><input type="checkbox" id="fish" name="sport"/>Fly Fishing</label></li>
            <li><label for="hunt"><input type="checkbox" id="hunt" name="sport" />Hunting</label></li>
            <li><label for="raft"><input type="checkbox" id="raft" name="sport" />Rafting</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="state-wrapper">    
        <h2>Choose a State:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><label for="AK" class="guide-available"><input type="checkbox" id="AK" name="state"/>Alaska</label></li>
            <li><label for="CA" class="guide-available"><input type="checkbox" id="CA" name="state"/>California</label></li>
            <li><label for="CO" class="guide-available"><input type="checkbox" id="CO" name="state"/>Colorado</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="results">    
        <h2>Available Guides:</h2>       
        <div data-category="guide ak fish">
            <h3>Joe's Alaska Fishing Tours</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-category="guide ak fish hunt">
            <h3>Mike's Alaska Fishing and Hunting Adventures</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-category="guide co fish raft">
            <h3>Jim's Colorado Rafting and Fishing Lodge</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-category="guide ca raft">
            <h3>California Whitewater Rafting</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**And the current jQuery (that doesn't quite work):**

```
function filterItems() {
    var state = $(":checkbox:checked").map( function(){ return this.value; }).get();
    var goodClasses = state.join(",");
    $(".guide").hide().filter(goodClasses).show();
}

filterItems();

$(":checkbox").change(filterItems);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay...  so I went back to the similar question that I had been looking at before posting this one.  You can see that question/solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786090/jquery-multiple-checkbox-filtering).  I should've spent some more time understanding that before posting this question.

**Here's a working solution**

In short, the solution I'm using loops through the groups of checkboxes by their name property (Pho3nixHun's solution in my reference question)

It starts off displaying the entire list of guides.  It will then filter to any and all sports that are chosen and will then filter those results with any and all states that are chosen.

**Here's the fully working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4SDesignStudio/n3EmN/91/)**

**And the working jQuery:**

```
var bySport = [], byState = [];

        $("input[name=sport]").on( "change", function() {
            if (this.checked) bySport.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
            else removeA(bySport, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
        });

        $("input[name=state]").on( "change", function() {
            if (this.checked) byState.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
            else removeA(byState, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
        });


        $("input").on( "change", function() {
            var str = "Include items \n";
            var selector = '', cselector = '', nselector = '';

            var $lis = $('.guide-list > div'),
                $checked = $('input:checked');  

            if ($checked.length) {  

                if (bySport.length) {       
                    if (str == "Include items \n") {
                        str += "    " + "with (" +  bySport.join(',') + ")\n";              
                        $($('input[name=sport]:checked')).each(function(index, bySport){
                            if(selector === '') {
                                selector += "[data-category~='" + bySport.id + "']";                    
                            } else {
                                selector += ",[data-category~='" + bySport.id + "']";   
                            }                
                        });                 
                    } else {
                        str += "    AND " + "with (" +  bySport.join(' OR ') + ")\n";               
                        $($('input[name=sport]:checked')).each(function(index, bySport){
                            selector += "[data-category~='" + bySport.id + "']";
                        });
                    }                           
                }

                if (byState.length) {                       
                    if (str == "Include items \n") {
                        str += "    " + "with (" +  byState.join(' OR ') + ")\n";                   
                        $($('input[name=state]:checked')).each(function(index, byState){
                            if(selector === '') {
                                selector += "[data-category~='" + byState.id + "']";                    
                            } else {
                                selector += ",[data-category~='" + byState.id + "']";   
                            }                
                        });                 
                    } else {
                        str += "    AND " + "with (" +  byState.join(' OR ') + ")\n";               
                        $($('input[name=state]:checked')).each(function(index, byState){
                            if(cselector === '') {
                                cselector += "[data-category~='" + byState.id + "']";                   
                            } else {
                                cselector += ",[data-category~='" + byState.id + "']";  
                            }                   
                        });
                    }           
                }



                $lis.hide(); 
                console.log(selector);
                console.log(cselector);
                console.log(nselector);

                if (cselector === '' && nselector === '') {         
                    $('.guide-list > div').filter(selector).show();
                } else if (cselector === '') {
                    $('.guide-list > div').filter(selector).filter(nselector).show();
                } else if (nselector === '') {
                    $('.guide-list > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).show();
                } else {
                    $('.guide-list > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).filter(nselector).show();
                }

            } else {
                $lis.show();
            }   

            $("#result").html(str); 

        });

        function removeA(arr) {
            var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
            while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
                what = a[--L];
                while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
                    arr.splice(ax, 1);
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
```

**And the HTML:**

```
<pre id=result> </pre> <!-- PRE simply shows filters in action in the results to double check everything's working.  Can remove -->

            <h2>Let's Find You a Guide</h2>
            <div class="filter-wrap">            
                <h3><strong>Select any or all activities you're interested in:</strong></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="fish" id="fish" /> Fishing</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="hunt" id="hunt" /> Hunting</label><br> 
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="charter" id="charter" /> Boat Charters</label></li>                     
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="hike" id="hike" /> Hiking</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="raft" id="raft" /> Rafting</label></li>  
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="other" id="other" /> Other</label></li>
                </ul>
                <h3><strong>Select any states you're willing to travel to:</strong></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state" value="AK" id="AK" /> Alaska</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state" value="CA" id="CA" /> California</label></li>
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state" value="CO" id="CO" /> Colorado</label></li>                  
                    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="state" value="NY" id="NY" /> New York</label></li>                    
                </ul>                                
            </div>
            <hr/>


            <div class="guide-list">
                <div class="guide" data-category="raft CA CO">Rafting in California or Colorado</div>
                <div class="guide" data-category="hike raft CO">Colorado Hiking and Rafting</div>
                <div class="guide" data-category="raft NY ">Upstate New York Rafting</div>
                <div class="guide" data-category="raft hunt NY">NY Hunting and Rafting Outfitters</div>  
                <div class="guide" data-category="raft NY">NYC Rafting Co.</div>                    
                <div class="guide" data-category="charter NY">Charter Boats of NYC</div>  
                <div class="guide" data-category="hike raft other CO">Colorado Hike Bike and Raft</div> 
                <div class="guide" data-category="charter other NY">Bike and Boat Rentals New York</div> 
                <div class="guide" data-category="fish CO">Colorado Fishing Tours</div> 
                <div class="guide" data-category="fish CA">Fishing Guides San Francisco</div>  
                <div class="guide" data-category="hike other CA">California Hiking and Other Stuff</div>  
                <div class="guide" data-category="raft AK">Alaskan Rafting Adventures</div>  
                <div class="guide" data-category="raft hunt CO">Denver Raft and Hunt</div>                  
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything's wrong with your fiddle code except that you didn't include "item" as class.

HTML

```js
function filterItems() {

    var state = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    
    console.log(state);
    
    var goodClasses = state.join("");
    console.log("Displaying : " + goodClasses);
    $(".item").hide().filter(goodClasses).show();
};

filterItems();

$(":checkbox").change(filterItems);
```

```css
ul {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    float:left;
    margin-left:2em;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    color:#666;
}
h3 {
    color:#99CC00;
    border:1px #666 solid;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <h2>Choose a Sport:</h2> 
<ul class="sport-list">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fish" name="sport" value=".fish">
        <label for="fish">Fly Fishing</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="hunt" name="sport" value=".hunt">
        <label for="hunt">Hunting</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="raft" name="sport" value=".raft">
        <label for="raft">Rafting</label>
    </li>
</ul>
 <h2>Choose a State:</h2>

<ul class="state-list">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="AK" name="state" value=".ak">
        <label for="AK" class="guide-available">Alaska</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="CA" name="state" value=".ca">
        <label for="CA" class="guide-available">California</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="CO" name="state" value=".co">
        <label for="CO" class="guide-available">Colorado</label>
    </li>
</ul>
 <h2>Available Guides:</h2> 
        <div>
<article class="item guide ak fish">
     <h3>Joe's Alaska Fishing Tours</h3>

</article>
<article class="item guide ak fish hunt">
     <h3>Mike's Alaska Fishing and Hunting Adventures</h3>

</article>
<article class="item guide co fish raft">
     <h3>Jim's Colorado Rafting and Fishing Lodge</h3>

</article>
<article class="item guide ca raft">
    <h3>California Whitewater Rafting</h3>
    </article>
            <div>
```

Comment: I saw that and just switched item to guide.  I think a better explanation of the problem is that I need "OR" instead of "AND" in the results.  For example, if you choose both Alaska and California, I need it to show results that include ak or ca.  I'm editing my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

please use this updated code,
You need to make class $('.guide') not $('.item') and  join(" ") should be join(",") in

```
function filterItems() {
    var state = $(":checkbox:checked").map( function(){ return this.value; }).get();
    var goodClasses = state.join(",");
    $(".guide").hide().filter(goodClasses).show();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    filterItems();

    $(":checkbox").change(filterItems);
});
```

Comment: Sagar - Thanks.  That was the simple mistake I made.  The issue I'm running into is that the filters don't work as two separate groups.  If the user chooses "Fishing" and then "California and Colorado", it still lists "Jim's Alaskan Fishing Tours" because it's filtering off of "Fishing" being checked but not taking into account the state filter.

Comment: Can you change the value of id from uppercase to lowercase? In checkbox Eg. AK to ak