# Jquery filtering with multiple Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, filtering

For a current project I am creating a  simple product catalogue which should be able to be filtered by Jquery with several sets of checkboxes.

In one single set when two or more checkboxes are checked the logic should be OR while when using two or more sets of checkboxes it should be AND.

A good (and working) example I am currently using can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22941156/5567735

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n3EmN/3/)

```
if (cselector === '' && nselector === '') {
    $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).show();
} else if (cselector === '') {
    $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).filter(nselector).show();
} else if (nselector === '') {
    $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).show();
} else {
    $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).filter(nselector).show();
}
```

My question regards this part of the code where the filters are being used in case they were selected. Now this works pretty good for the 3 filters that are being used in the example. What I am wondering is there some better way to be doing this? In my case I want to add some more filters and then this part of the code will get messy pretty soon when I have to add a lot more if statements.

So basically my question is: Using this setup, how would you add more filters so you have 6 or 7 in the end instead of the current 3?

Thanks a lot,
Peter

P.S. I also appreciate tips for completely different approaches but as I already put quite some time into this I would really like to get it work this way.

Comment: Is it possible you can amend the HTML? This would be *much* simpler if you had each property to be filtered in its own `data` attribute.

Comment: Yes, I can freely change the HTML. Can you explain a bit more detailed how the properties would be filtered in seperated data attributes? Thx!

Comment: though it doesn't resemble your current code at all, you could do [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/n3EmN/168/)

Comment: Thanks @billyonecan that seems to be working just fine and with much less code! I really appreciate it! Is there any way I can mark your comment to be the accepted answer? Cheers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your current approach isn't very dynamic, selectors and arrays are being hardcoded, so each time you add new filter options you'll have to add code to handle it.

Instead, just bind a change handler to all filter checkboxes, you can collect up their values, and group them by their respective names, eg:

```
var $filterCheckboxes = $( '.filter-checkboxes' );

$filterCheckboxes.on( 'change', function() {

  var selectedFilters = {};

  $filterCheckboxes.filter( ':checked' ).each( function() {

    if ( ! selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty( this.name ) ) {
      selectedFilters[ this.name ] = [];
    }

    selectedFilters[ this.name ].push( this.value );

  } );

} );
```

This will create an object containing `input-name -> value array` pairs, eg:

```
selectedFilters = {
  'fl-colour': [ 'red', 'green' ],
  'fl-size': [ 'tiny' ]
};
```

You can then loop over each `selectedFilters`, and filter your `.flower` elements. If a `.flower` element matches a value in each named set, we return true so that the element is included in the `$filteredResults` collection:

```
// create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
var $filteredResults = $( '.flower' );

// loop over the selected filter name -> (array) values pairs
$.each( selectedFilters, function( name, filterValues ) {

  // filter each .flower element
  $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter( function() {

    var matched = false,
        currentFilterValues = $( this ).data( 'category' ).split( ' ' );

    // loop over each category value in the current .flower's data-category
    $.each( currentFilterValues, function( _, currentFilterValue ) {

      // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
      // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
      // set of filters, we only need to match once

      if ( $.inArray( currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1 ) {
        matched = true;
        return false;
      }

    } );    

    // if matched is true the current .flower element is returned
    return matched;    

  } );

} );
```

Then simply hide all the `.flower` elements, and show the `$filteredResults`, eg:

```
$( '.flower' ).hide().filter( $filteredResults ).show();
```

#### [Here's an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3EmN/171/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks also for the detailed documentation - understanding a solution is always better than just getting a solution to work (:

Comment: This is brilliant. Epic. Incredible. Thank you so much for taking the time to make such a complete example.

Comment: Trying this code I get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" for var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').

Comment: Putting ajax first doesn't give the error anymore, but still nothing happens.   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I Can't explain you how's happy happy i find your example you are rocking man

Comment: this is an excellent example, please check the fiddle and make your own adjustments accordingly

Comment: I had to modify this solution slightly to work with .NET WebForms, which uses a unique "name" attribute for each checkbox - but otherwise this answer worked perfectly for me and is so much faster in the UI than UpdatePanels and PostBacks. Thanks for saving me hours of work!

Comment: This solution is great, but I'm curious how I would take it one step further and refine the filter. For example only display the elements that have all the filter selections, not just the elements that contain at leat 1. For example, using your fiddle... If Africa and Europe was selected, could I refine the code to show only those elements that contain both filters (Lavendar and Stinging Nettle) and not include those that contains at only one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fork of the jsfiddle from billyonecan. Differences are...

- An unchecked box means that property is excluded from results
- All checkboxes are checked by default (all results shown)
- At least one checkbox for each filter group must be checked
- If a filter group does not submit a filter, all results are hidden
- If a new filter group is added it will be automatically handled

  ( ( a||b||c ) && ( x||y||z ) && ( 1||2||3 )... )

. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ojolo/gtp14du1/82/)

```js
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

  // Read All Available Filter Groups
  var allFilters = [];
  $filterCheckboxes.each(function() {
   if ($.inArray(this.name,allFilters) == -1){
     allFilters.push(this.name);
    }  
  });
//  console.log(allFilters); 






$filterCheckboxes.on('change', function() {

  // create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
  var $filteredResults = $('.item');

 var $filterCategoryApplied = 0;
  
  $.each(allFilters, function(arIndex, filterName) {
  // console.log(filterName); 
 var $filterCheckboxCategory = $('input[name='+filterName+']').filter(':checked');
 
  console.log(filterName + ' length = ' + $filterCheckboxCategory.length);
   
   if ( $filterCheckboxCategory.length === 0 ) {
//    alert('none checked for ' + filterName);
    $filteredResults = [];
   }
  });




console.log('start checking');



 // Read Selectetd Filters
  var selectedFilters = {};
  $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
    if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
      selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
    }
    selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);
  });
  
  

  



  // loop over the selected filter name -> (array) values pairs
  $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {

//console.log(selectedFilters['fl-colour'].length); 
//console.log(name); 
//console.log(filterValues); 
//console.log(filterValues.length); 



    // filter each .flower element
    $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {

      var matched = false,
        currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');

      // loop over each category value in the current .flower's data-category
      $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {

        // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
        // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
        // set of filters, we only need to match once

        if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
          matched = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      // if matched is true the current .flower element is returned
      return matched;

    });
  });

  $('.item').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: #646464;
}


.items-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 3% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.items {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

.items div.item {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0 1%;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 0 1px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id=result> </pre>

<div class="items-wrap">

  <h3 style="font-size:13px; font-weight:normal;">Filter Items</h3>
  <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>By colour:</strong></p>
  
  <form id='filters'>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="red" id="red" checked /> Red</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="yellow" id="yellow" checked /> Yellow</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="green" id="green" checked /> Green</label>

    <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>By size:</strong></p>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="small" id="small" checked /> Small</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="medium" id="medium" checked /> Medium</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="large" id="large" checked /> Large</label>
  
    <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>By Shape:</strong></p>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-shape" value="square" id="square" checked /> Square</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-shape" value="circle" id="circle" checked /> Circle</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-shape" value="triangle" id="triangle" checked /> Triangle</label>
  </form>

</div>



<div class="items">
  <div class="item" data-id="rss" data-category="red small square">red small square</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="yss" data-category="yellow small square">yellow small square</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="gss" data-category="green small square">green small square</div>
  
  <div class="item" data-id="rms" data-category="red medium square">red medium square</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="yms" data-category="yellow medium square">yellow medium square</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="gms" data-category="green medium square">green medium square</div>
  
  <div class="item" data-id="rls" data-category="red large square">red large square</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="yls" data-category="yellow large square">yellow large square</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="gls" data-category="green large square">green large square</div>







  <div class="item" data-id="rsc" data-category="red small circle">red small circle</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="ysc" data-category="yellow small circle">yellow small circle</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="gsc" data-category="green small circle">green small circle</div>
  
  <div class="item" data-id="rmc" data-category="red medium circle">red medium circle</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="ymc" data-category="yellow medium circle">yellow medium circle</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="gmc" data-category="green medium circle">green medium circle</div>
  
  <div class="item" data-id="rlc" data-category="red large circle">red large circle</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="ylc" data-category="yellow large circle">yellow large circle</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="glc" data-category="green large circle">green large circle</div>
  
  
  
  
  
  <div class="item" data-id="rst" data-category="red small triangle">red small triangle</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="yst" data-category="yellow small triangle">yellow small triangle</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="gst" data-category="green small triangle">green small triangle</div>
  
  <div class="item" data-id="rmt" data-category="red medium triangle">red medium triangle</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="ymt" data-category="yellow medium triangle">yellow medium triangle</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="gmt" data-category="green medium triangle">green medium triangle</div>
  
  <div class="item" data-id="rlt" data-category="red large triangle">red large triangle</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="ylt" data-category="yellow large triangle">yellow large triangle</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="glt" data-category="green large triangle">green large triangle</div>  
  



</div>
```