# Jquery filtering with multiple combination checkboxes

Tags: jquery, arrays, filter, filtering

I'm trying to filter with multiple checkboxes and I've used the code from the answer in this example: [Jquery filtering with multiple Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011034/jquery-filtering-with-multiple-checkboxes) It works really well but I need the results to show a combination of the checkboxes. At the moment it only matches the checkbox filter result exactly. I want it to show all results if the objects contain any 1 of the array, not the array exactly. I can't use isotope for my particular project but it would be like this isotope example:

```
  <a href="http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/btFfG">
```

EDIT: It's this bit of code inparticular I know needs changing. At the moment it loops through the array and shows the content if the element matches the checkbox category exactely. I need it to loop through the array and show the content if any of the categories match any of the array variables:

```
       // create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
        var $filteredResults = $('.card');

        // loop over the selected filter name -> (array) values pairs
        $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {

            // filter each .card element
            $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {

                var matched = false;
                var currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');

                // loop over each category value in the current .card's data-category
                $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {

                    // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
                    // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
                    // set of filters, we only need to match once
                    if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
                      matched = true;
                      return false;
                    }
                });

                // if matched is true the current .card element is returned
                return matched;

            });
        });
```

Comment: Is there something in particular about the code that you are having trouble understanding? When you use code from an online example, like you've done here, it is important to try to understand what is being done, why, and how it is implemented. That way you aren't surprised by nasty bugs, or at least have an idea of where to look. As it is, random internet code isn't doing exactly what you want, and you're asking for someone to fix it for you. It would be good to show that you've tried to understand, and are stuck, [with a short example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22754/218143) to start

Comment: Thanks, I've just edited my answer. I know the part of the code i need to change and i understand what's there. i think I'm almost there, i'm just trying to get my head around the logic and function needed. I've edited my question above to hopefully explain it better...

Answer (score 0):

In the outer loop:

```
$.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {...
```

You are iterating over each of the selected filters progressively eliminating those that don't match the filter.

```
$filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {...
```

The only items that make it through satisfy *all* the filters (i.e. you are doing a logical AND operation).  Instead, you need to filter the `.card` items once, returning true if any of the `$(this).data('category')` values for the item match any of the the selected filters.  This way you are doing a logical OR operation instead.