# JQuery multiple checkbox filtering multiple (more than 3) categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, filtering

I have to create a page that lists 19 courses. I would like to add filtering functionality to it that would allow a visitor to filter the courses by different characteristics (job function, date, duration, location, product, etc).

I came across this [previous question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786090/jquery-multiple-checkbox-filtering) that came close to solving my problem. However the solution only has three sets of checkboxes and I need 8 sets.

I have some code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SMErickson7/xpvt214o/979495/), which can filter the first three categories but beyond that it doesn't filter.

```js
var byProperty = [],
  byColor = [],
  byLocation = [];

$("input[name=cat1]").on("change", function() {
  if (this.checked) byProperty.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
  else removeA(byProperty, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
});

$("input[name=cat2]").on("change", function() {
  if (this.checked) byColor.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
  else removeA(byColor, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
});

$("input[name=cat3]").on("change", function() {
  if (this.checked) byLocation.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
  else removeA(byLocation, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
});

$("input").on("change", function() {
  var str = "Include items \n";
  var selector = '',
    cselector = '',
    nselector = '';

  var $lis = $('.courses > div'),
    $checked = $('input:checked');

  if ($checked.length) {

    if (byProperty.length) {
      if (str == "Include items \n") {
        str += "    " + "with (" + byProperty.join(',') + ")\n";
        $($('input[name=cat1]:checked')).each(function(index, byProperty) {
          if (selector === '') {
            selector += "[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";
          } else {
            selector += ",[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";
          }
        });
      } else {
        str += "    AND " + "with (" + byProperty.join(' OR ') + ")\n";
        $($('input[name=cat2]:checked')).each(function(index, byProperty) {
          selector += "[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";
        });
      }
    }

    if (byColor.length) {
      if (str == "Include items \n") {
        str += "    " + "with (" + byColor.join(' OR ') + ")\n";
        $($('input[name=cat2]:checked')).each(function(index, byColor) {
          if (selector === '') {
            selector += "[data-category~='" + byColor.id + "']";
          } else {
            selector += ",[data-category~='" + byColor.id + "']";
          }
        });
      } else {
        str += "    AND " + "with (" + byColor.join(' OR ') + ")\n";
        $($('input[name=cat2]:checked')).each(function(index, byColor) {
          if (cselector === '') {
            cselector += "[data-category~='" + byColor.id + "']";
          } else {
            cselector += ",[data-category~='" + byColor.id + "']";
          }
        });
      }
    }

    if (byLocation.length) {
      if (str == "Include items \n") {
        str += "    " + "with (" + byLocation.join(' OR ') + ")\n";
        $($('input[name=cat3]:checked')).each(function(index, byLocation) {
          if (selector === '') {
            selector += "[data-category~='" + byLocation.id + "']";
          } else {
            selector += ",[data-category~='" + byLocation.id + "']";
          }
        });
      } else {
        str += "    AND " + "with (" + byLocation.join(' OR ') + ")\n";
        $($('input[name=cat3]:checked')).each(function(index, byLocation) {
          if (nselector === '') {
            nselector += "[data-category~='" + byLocation.id + "']";
          } else {
            nselector += ",[data-category~='" + byLocation.id + "']";
          }
        });
      }
    }

    $lis.hide();
    console.log(selector);
    console.log(cselector);
    console.log(nselector);

    if (cselector === '' && nselector === '') {
      $('.courses > div').filter(selector).show();
    } else if (cselector === '') {
      $('.courses > div').filter(selector).filter(nselector).show();
    } else if (nselector === '') {
      $('.courses > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).show();
    } else {
      $('.courses > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).filter(nselector).show();
    }

  } else {
    $lis.show();
  }

  $("#result").html(str);

});

function removeA(arr) {
  var what, a = arguments,
    L = a.length,
    ax;
  while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
    what = a[--L];
    while ((ax = arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
      arr.splice(ax, 1);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: #646464;
}

.filters-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.filters {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.filters div {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  height: 68px;
  line-height: 68px;
  padding: 0 5%;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 0 1px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="filters-wrap">

  <h3>Category 1</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat1" value="1-a" id="1-a" />1-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat1" value="1-b" id="1-b" />1-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat1" value="1-c" id="1-c" />1-C</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 2</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat2" value="2-a" id="2-a" />2-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat2" value="2-b" id="2-b" />2-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat2" value="2-c" id="2-c" />2-C</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 3</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat3" value="3-a" id="3-a" />3-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat3" value="3-b" id="3-b" />3-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat3" value="3-c" id="3-c" />3-C</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 4</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat4" value="4-a" id="4-a" />4-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat4" value="4-b" id="4-b" />4-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat4" value="4-c" id="4-c" />4-C</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 5</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat5" value="5-a" id="5-a" />5-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat5" value="5-b" id="5-b" />5-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat5" value="5-c" id="5-c" />5-C</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 6</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat6" value="6-a" id="6-a" />6-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat6" value="6-b" id="6-b" />6-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat6" value="6-c" id="6-c" />6-C</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 7</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat7" value="7-a" id="7-a" />7-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat7" value="7-b" id="7-b" />7-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat7" value="7-c" id="7-c" />7-A</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 8</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat8" value="8-a" id="8-a" />8-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat8" value="8-b" id="8-b" />8-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat8" value="8-c" id="8-c" />8-C</label><br>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="courses">
  <div class="course" data-id="course01" data-category="1-a 2-b 4-c">Course 1 [cat 1A, 2B, 4C]</div>
  <div class="course" data-id="course02" data-category="3-c 6-b 7-c 8-a">Course 2 [cat 3C, 6BB, 7C, 8A]</div>
  <div class="course" data-id="course03" data-category="3-a 6-b 8-c">Course 3 [cat 3A, 6B, 8C]</div>
  <div class="course" data-id="course04" data-category="5-c 6-b">Course 4 [cat 5C, 6B]</div>
</div>
```

How could I edit my code that would incorporate the remaining categories (4-8)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something important but, apart from being too specific for the case at hand, the original code is a bit too complicated and repeats code unnecessarily (e.g. it defines a specific array for each category and selector)... which made me write something a bit different.

The whole thing could be *simplified* and made more generic by having an arrays of arrays to hold the category values instead of arrays in separated variables. That way, if you want to add/remove categories in your filtering, you just need to specify the new number of categories instead of adding/removing dozens of lines of code per category.

Also, if instead of creating a selector (that could be huge) you change a little the HTML and make a different use of the data-attributes (having one data-attribute per category instead of a single big data-attribute that contains all of them). <sub>Note: thinking about it while writing the answer, this step could be optional.</sub>

---

So here is a list of the changes I made:

1. Modified the values of the checkboxes to only contain the letter instead of number-letter. This was just to simplify and to go with the following step.
2. Broke the big data-category into smaller data-categories (one per category, and only if needed). This was done to "normalize" the data.
3. Added class `.hidden` to the styles... that hides the element to which it is added.

With those changes the (commented) code looks like this:

```js
// constant: number of categories (this could be calculated if properly designed)
const NUM_CATEGORIES = 8;

// every time an option is clicked 
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function() {

  // generate an array with the checked options per category
  let selected = new Array(NUM_CATEGORIES);
  // for each category
  for (let x = 0; x < NUM_CATEGORIES; x++) {
    // generate an array
    selected[x] = [];
    // populate it with the values of the checked options
    $("input[name=cat" + (x+1) + "]:checked").each(function() { 
      selected[x].push($(this).val());
    });
  }
  
  // for each course
  $(".course").each(function() {
    // by default it is going to be displayed
    let show = true;
    
    // we check all the categories
    for (let x = 0; x < NUM_CATEGORIES; x++) {
      // if they have a checked value
      if (selected[x].length) {
        // if the course has a value for that category
        if (this.dataset["cat-" + (x+1)]) {
          // convert the value into an array (in case there are multiple)
          var catValues = this.dataset["cat-" + (x+1)].split(",");
          // check if any of the values of the array is a selected category
          show = catValues.some(val => selected[x].indexOf(val) >= 0);
          // if not, hide and no need to keep checking
          if (!show) break;
        } 
        // if the course does not have a value for that checked category
        else {
          // hide and no need to keep checking
          show = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    
    // hide or show depending on if it has fulfilled the condition
    $(this).toggleClass("hidden", !show);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: #646464;
}

.filters-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.filters {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.filters div {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  height: 68px;
  line-height: 68px;
  padding: 0 5%;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 0 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.courses {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50px;
}

.course.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters-wrap">

  <h3>Category 1</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat1" value="a" id="1-a" />1-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat1" value="b" id="1-b" />1-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat1" value="c" id="1-c" />1-C</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 2</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat2" value="a" id="2-a" />2-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat2" value="b" id="2-b" />2-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat2" value="c" id="2-c" />2-C</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 3</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat3" value="a" id="3-a" />3-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat3" value="b" id="3-b" />3-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat3" value="c" id="3-c" />3-C</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 4</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat4" value="a" id="4-a" />4-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat4" value="b" id="4-b" />4-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat4" value="c" id="4-c" />4-C</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 5</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat5" value="a" id="5-a" />5-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat5" value="b" id="5-b" />5-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat5" value="c" id="5-c" />5-C</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 6</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat6" value="a" id="6-a" />6-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat6" value="b" id="6-b" />6-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat6" value="c" id="6-c" />6-C</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 7</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat7" value="a" id="7-a" />7-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat7" value="b" id="7-b" />7-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat7" value="c" id="7-c" />7-A</label><br>
  </form>
  <h3>Category 8</h3>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat8" value="a" id="8-a" />8-A</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat8" value="b" id="8-b" />8-B</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cat8" value="c" id="8-c" />8-C</label><br>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="courses">
  <div class="course" data-id="course01" data-cat-1="a" data-cat-2="b" data-cat-4="c">Course 1 [cat 1A, 2B, 4C]</div>
  <div class="course" data-id="course02" data-cat-3="c" data-cat-6="b,c" data-cat-7="c" data-cat-8="a">Course 2 [cat 3C, 6BC, 7C, 8A]</div>
  <div class="course" data-id="course03" data-cat-3="a" data-cat-6="b" data-cat-8="c">Course 3 [cat 3A, 6B, 8C]</div>
  <div class="course" data-id="course04" data-cat-5="c" data-cat-6="b">Course 4 [cat 5C, 6B]</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a change to the code so it works too if a course can fit into multiple values of the same category (e.g. the flowers example linked, the same flower can have different colors). The only thing would be to specify the list of values separated by comma.